# Test RxJava2 Flowable Query Room

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2, android-room

I've been trying to write unit tests for my Room database, which I've done in the past when I have queries return a list and I create a database that allows main thread queries, but now that I'm trying to test with RxJava values I have no luck.

Here is my DAO code:

```
@Dao
interface AccountDAO {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM account")
    fun getAll(): Flowable<List<Account>>

    @Insert
    fun insert(accounts: List<Account>): List<Long>

    //...
}
```

And here is my database testing code, where I've tried a few things to get it to pass:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class CCDatabaseTest {
    //...

    @JvmField @Rule val mainActivity = ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>(MainActivity::class.java)

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        val context = mainActivity.activity
        database = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context, CCDatabase::class.java).allowMainThreadQueries().build()
        accountDao = database.accountDao()
        transactionDao = database.transactionDao()
    }

    //...

    @Test
    fun testWriteReadAccount() {
        val testAccount = Account(TEST_ACCOUNT_NAME, TEST_ACCOUNT_BALANCE)

        val ids = accountDao.insert(listOf(testAccount))
        assertEquals(1, ids.size)

        val accountsFlowable = accountDao.getAll()
        val testSubscriber = TestSubscriber<List<Account>>()
        accountsFlowable.subscribe(testSubscriber)

        testSubscriber.assertNoErrors()
        // Fails: testSubscriber.assertValueCount(1)
        // Fails: testSubscriber.assertValue(listOf(testAccount))
        // Fails: testSubscriber.assertResult(listOf(testAccount))
    }

    //...
}
```

If anyone would actually like to see or test run the code, please check out the app-refresh module of this repository: https://github.com/adammc331/cashcaretaker

DAO: https://github.com/AdamMc331/CashCaretaker/blob/develop/app-refresh/src/main/java/com/adammcneilly/cashcaretaker/daos/AccountDAO.kt

Test class: https://github.com/AdamMc331/CashCaretaker/blob/develop/app-refresh/src/androidTest/java/com/adammcneilly/cashcaretaker/data/CCDatabaseTest.kt

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As part of my search to answer this, I commented on a [Medium post by Florina Muntenescu](https://medium.com/google-developers/room-rxjava-acb0cd4f3757) and she [responded](https://medium.com/@florina.muntenescu/check-the-tests-here-and-make-sure-youre-using-the-instanttaskexecutorrule-for-your-test-f756ecb8c9e7) with the answer.

I needed to include the [`InstantTaskExecutorRule`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/core/executor/testing/InstantTaskExecutorRule.html) in my test class. This replaces the background task executor with one that runs everything synchronously. In order to use this, I added the following line to my module's build.gradle file, note that while I had to exclude certain modules (I got a support lib discrepancy between app and test app) you may not:

```
androidTestCompile ("android.arch.core:core-testing:$roomLibraryVersion") {
    exclude module: 'support-compat'
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude module: 'support-core-utils'
}
```

Now, with that added, my test class looks like this:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class CCDatabaseTest {
    // ...

    @JvmField @Rule val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
    @JvmField @Rule val mainActivity = ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>(MainActivity::class.java)

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        val context = mainActivity.activity
        database = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context, CCDatabase::class.java).allowMainThreadQueries().build()
        accountDao = database.accountDao()
    }

    // ...

    @Test
    fun testWriteReadAccount() {
        val testAccount = Account(TEST_ACCOUNT_NAME, TEST_ACCOUNT_BALANCE)

        val ids = accountDao.insert(listOf(testAccount))
        assertEquals(1, ids.size)

        accountDao.getAll()
                .test()
                .assertValue(listOf(testAccount))
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `testObserver.awaitTerminalEvent()` before running your assertions.

Comment: Tried this, but it just hangs for a long time as if it couldn't return anything. That doesn't make sense though, because I just inserted something and verified that it worked.

Comment: I've also ran the app and verified this works by adding an account and seeing it displayed on the screen, but it's only when I'm trying to test a flowable that I'm having issues. I admittedly don't have a lot of experience with testing RxJAva.